# How to achieve tables for data entry xamarin

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a Xamarin mobile app and looking to achieve a table component with input fields for data entry like the table image shown below. What the best solution to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Are the fields dynamic?

Comment: No, just need to enter the data and click a save button

Comment: I mean, you can achieve this with a Grid, but if you have a big data, it's better to use a ListView

Comment: I can with a grid but its tedious to manage, idk if their like a plugin or a simpler way to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use datagrid from Syncfusion (https://www.syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/datagrid)

Syncfusion solution is paid, but there is a community license and you can register to use it for free. Check out https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense